# Check for double letters with indexOf?

Tags: java

I need to check if there are more than one of the same letters in a word.

For example, in the name 'bob' the index of 'b' is '0 and 2' but indexOf only creates a sees the first index of 0.

What I need is for it to check and then skip over 0 and go further down the work and check for more of the same letters. Here is what I have so far.

```
String wordNow = "bob";
letterGuess = console.next().toUpperCase();

letterIndex = wordNow.indexOf(letterGuess);
System.out.println(letterIndex);
```

OUTPUT: 0

If anyone has a good efficient way of doing this, i'm all ears.

Comment: What is `console`?

Comment: @EJP It's the scanner class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.lastIndexOf` for this. Since both functions will return -1 if not found, then to check if there is more than one instance, you can just compare the values

```
return wordNow.indexOf(letterGuess) != wordNow.lastIndexOf(letterGuess);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple versions of the method indexOf. One of them takes an index itself! Just read the javadoc for the string class carefully. You see there is even one called "lastIndexOf" which would come in really handy.

You can use that for example to see if there are other occurrences of that char "behind" the first index you found.

In any case: the real answer here is that you should study the documentation of classes extensively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring by excluding the matching character, as below:

```
String wordNow = "bob";
letterGuess = console.next().toUpperCase();

letterIndex = wordNow.indexOf(letterGuess);
System.out.println(letterIndex);

if(letterIndex >= 0) {
   int secondIndex = wordNow.subString(letterIndex+1).indexOf(letterGuess);
   System.out.println(secondIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to simply just search for the element you are looking for (assuming no order or distribution over the input string).

```
public boolean isCharacterRepeatedIgnoreCase(String inputString, Character c) {
    int numFound = 0;
    final Character chUpper = Character.toUpperCase(c);
    final String upperCaseString = inputString.toUpperCase();
    for (int i=0;i<upperCaseString.length();++i) {
        if (upperCaseString.charAt(i) == chUpper) {
            numFound++;
        }
        if (numFound > 1) {
            return true;
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Note, I have not run the above code. So please write proper unit tests if you plan on considering the above. Also, I have assumed that your character can fit into 16 bits. You probably want to do something around `String` or `toUpperCase(int)` to handle Unicode, see [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(int)).